# Keras: how to check max_queue_size is sufficient in fit_generator?

Tags: python, keras, queue, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

From `fit_generator` [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/):

> max_queue_size: Integer. Maximum size for the generator queue. If
>   unspecified, max_queue_size will default to 10.

For now I'm setting `max_queue_size = workers * 2`, but I want to check 2 bad cases:

1. How to check if queue is full about all the time.
2. How to check if queue is empty about all the time.